# Fusker link parsing; code to specific that the values from two ranges MUST match

Tags: javascript, php, url

So, while I'm fairly tech savvy, I know just about nothing when it comes to scripts and coding. What I'm trying to do is find how to write out a link with two separate ranges in which the two numbers MUST match to generate the proper URL (it's for fusker links).

For example:
I know the brackets indicate a range in which it will identify every number in that range and generate a link with it, however, it does it for ALL of them in order. I get 5300/5301.zip, and 5300/5302.zip and so on.

/zips/[5300-5399]/[5300-5399].zip

What I want is what code I have to input in order for it to require those two values within the ranges match one another to generate the proper URL.

EXAMPLE: /zips/5399/5399.zip

So that way it ONLY generates the URL if both the numbers generated match.

If it helps, this is the website/page I'm using to generate the links for me: https://www.neodownloader.com/tools/link-builder/

Thanks in advance.

~Nick

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with regular JavaScript - your question seems to be about using NeoDownloader's website, which isn't actually part of StackOverflow. To generate a list of links in that range in that format, just do:

```js
let counter = 5300;
let limit = 5399;

for (counter; counter <= limit; counter++) {
  console.log(`/zips/${counter}/${counter}.zip`);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

(note the above only displays the last fifty results)

Comment: Thank you. The only code I know is basic HTML from my Freshman year of high school. I tried to learn php once, but it gave me a headache.

Comment: How would I use the script you provided for me outside of here? Like in an HTML file written in notepad, to which I could edit the script and then just run/open the file in Chrome?

Comment: Yeah - you can make a very basic HTML file containing `<script></script>` tags, then just chuck the script I have above (ignore the `.as-console-wrapper` part, it's just to style the console output) in between those script tags.